# Difference between [mysql] and [mysqld] in MySQL configuration file

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-5.1, configuration

There are multiple sections in MySQL configuration file:

- [mysql]
- [mysqld]
- [myisamchk]
- [mysqld_safe]
- [mysqlhotcopy]
- [mysqldump]
- [client]

I found that same variables with different values have been defined under these sections.

- What are the specific purpose behind defining these sections?
- Is it necessary to define all?
- How MySQL interprets these variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL calls these section **"Groups"**. The [mysqld] group contains the variables apply to the MySQL **Server** (the mysqld process). The [mysql] group contains the variables for the **client** program (mysql).

The [client] option group is read by all client programs (but not by mysqld), so "mysql", "mysqldump" etc...

None of these groups are mandatory but usually we set at least the [mysqld] because it's where we configure the server.

About how MySQL interprets these variables, MySQL Documentation says:

> If an option group name is the same as a program name, options in the
>   group apply specifically to that program.

Max

Comment: Can you provide me the MySQL documentation link referring the your `highlighted statement` ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html